# <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused> in HortonWorks

Tags: hadoop, errno, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to run hadoop on a VM that I have downloaded from HortonWorks Sandbox (very new at working with hadoop, mahout...)

I am using HortonWorks environment to create a table and start working with it.
But the problem is that when I upload my file and click on creating a table I get this error:

HCatClient error on create table:

Could somebody please help me understand what is happening and how I should fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to the Ambari portal port 8080 and then start the WebHCat Server.